# Sitecore JSS with Vue - Json are not identical between connected and disconnected mode

Tags: jss

In disconnected mode I have a "value" that I don't have in connected mode.
So if I need to do this:
`{{ fields.items.value.length }}` it's working only in disconnected mode and not after a deploy...

Disconnected (fields.items.value.length):
[image]

Connected (fields.items.length):
[image]

What can I do ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in JSS tech preview 3. (one that I actually fixed yesterday!) It will be fixed in the next release.

In the meantime as a workaround, something like `const items = Array.isArray(fields.items) ? fields.items : fields.items.value;` or `const items = fields.items.value || fields.items;` should do the trick.